# How to handle NULL values when using DATE or CAST functions in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string field 'ShippedDate' in the following format (1998-04-06 0:00:00) that I need to convert to datetime format. I have tried using DATE and CAST functions, but because there are NULL values in the field I am getting the following error: Invalid timestamp: 'NULL'.

I tried using those functions with IFNULL (see below), but I'm still getting the same error. How do I get around this issue? Thanks!

```
SELECT IFNULL(CAST(ShippedDate AS DATETIME),null)

SELECT IFNULL(DATE(ShippedDate),null)
```

Comment: It would appear that your "null" values are actually strings containing the textual value of `'null'`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! The database was provided by a potential employer for a series of technical exercises... I think they purposely put those text values in there :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting) instead.

```sql
SELECT SAFE_CAST(ShippedDate AS DATETIME);
```